# Word wrap function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a Javascript function which takes a 1, 2 or 3 word phrase and returns the same phrase, but the first found space is replaced with a `<br>`

so

```
Hello My World
```

becomes

```
Hello<br>My World
```

or

```
Hello World
```

becomes

```
Hello<br>World.
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could equally change this to a set of options, but passing blanks works fine too for optional ordered params:

http://jsfiddle.net/MHRbF/

```
<div id='test'></div>
<div id='test2'></div>
<div id='test3'></div>
```

Then in js:

```
function replaceMe(sString, sTarget, sWith, nCount){
    if(!sString) return 'Please provide a string';
    if(!sTarget) sTarget = /\s/;
    if(!sWith) sWith= '<br/>';
    if(!nCount) nCount = 1;
    for(var c = 0; c < nCount; c++)  sString= sString.replace(sTarget, sWith);
    return sString;
}

x = 'Hello Crazy World Full of People!';
y = replaceMe(x);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = y;
y = replaceMe(x,'','',10);
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = y;
y = replaceMe(x,'','',2);
document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = y;
```

You get the idea how this becomes pretty flexible.

Answer (score 2):

```
function space2br(str, limit){
    for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        str = str.replace(/\s/, '<br>');
    return str;
}

space2br('Hello My World', 1); // "Hello<br>My World"
space2br('Hello My World', 2); // "Hello<br>My<br>World"

function firstSpace2br(str){
    return space2br(str, 1);
}

firstSpace2br('Hello My Favourite World'); // "Hello<br>My Favourite World"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple regex replace

```
'Hello My World'.replace(/\s/, '<br />')
```